# Could moderators be given access to how much spam their site(s) see?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam, analytics

Would it be possible to add spam blocked & flagged (and maybe other internal) stats to the super-secret-ana______-page?

This probably would fit the description of "low priority" pretty well, though.  It came up in TL earlier as a curiosity, and it's still pretty much just a curiosity, but it's one I'd really like to see implemented.

By which I mean: the mod tools are designed to help us see our site health. Spammers would logically only attack a site they think will have views, so knowing how much spam we get gives us deep, valuable insight into how our site is doing. (Dear gods, that was supposed to be sarcastic but actually made a little bit of sense somehow.)

Comment: Analytics? :O *amazing!*

Comment: The most amazing thing about the super secret analytics is how useless they are @bjb568

Answer (score 8):

While this isn't strictly related to spam analytics, there's a useful query you can run as a moderator to identify incidents of spam that the community caught but moderators might not have seen. Run a query like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=locked%3a1%20deleted%3a1

replacing "stackoverflow.com" with your site, and you'll get a listing of the most recent posts that have been locked and deleted. This almost always indicates community spam- or offensive-flagged material that was destroyed. Shog9 suggested this to me, and it has proven to be really valuable on Stack Overflow for identifying and cleaning up after spammers that come in when we're most lightly staffed.

Analytics would still be great, but thought I'd post this in case it can help other moderators.

Comment: Oooh; something cool to bookmark!